# How to resolve "Cannot read property 'map' of null" after npm start?

Tags: angular, webpack

I have an Angular 4.3.2 app that has been running for a few years. I need to fix some vulnerabilities that were found in the various packages (many of which were fixed with a npm audit fix). However after I fixed a bunch of vulnerabilities in the package.json (and upgrading some code  in the package*  files), I then do a 'npm start' and webpage does not load. After inspecting the page and checking the console, it prints this out:

```
core.es5.js?a1b3:1020 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
    at splitDepsDsl (core.es5.js?a1b3:8712)
    at _def (core.es5.js?a1b3:10695)
    at directiveDef (core.es5.js?a1b3:10652)
    at View_JhiMainComponent_Host_0 (JhiMainComponent_Host.html:1)
    at proxyClass (compiler.es5.js?7057:14975)
    at resolveDefinition (core.es5.js?a1b3:8756)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js?a1b3:9859)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js?a1b3:3333)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (core.es5.js?a1b3:4768)
    at eval (core.es5.js?a1b3:4546)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.es5.js?a1b3:1020
app.main.ts?ebe9:13 TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
    at splitDepsDsl (core.es5.js?a1b3:8712)
    at _def (core.es5.js?a1b3:10695)
    at directiveDef (core.es5.js?a1b3:10652)
    at View_JhiMainComponent_Host_0 (JhiMainComponent_Host.html:1)
    at proxyClass (compiler.es5.js?7057:14975)
    at resolveDefinition (core.es5.js?a1b3:8756)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js?a1b3:9859)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js?a1b3:3333)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (core.es5.js?a1b3:4768)
    at eval (core.es5.js?a1b3:4546)
```

The code is on line 8737 of a core.js file, which isn't really anything I could edit to fix:

```
 * @param {?} deps
 * @return {?}
 */
function splitDepsDsl(deps) {
    return deps.map(function (value) {
```

Anyone know what I can do to try and fix this?
Here is my package.json:

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jhipster": "0.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "keycloak-angular": "7.2.0",
    "keycloak-js": "8.0.2",
    "ng-jhipster": "0.2.12",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "ng2-webstorage": "1.8.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "1.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "0.5.1",
    "ngx-webstorage": "5.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "swagger-ui": "^3.32.5",
    "swagger-ui-dist": "^3.32.5",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.0",
    "tether": "1.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/node": "8.0.18",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "3.0.4",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.2",
    "base-href-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.12",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "2.2.2",
    "codelyzer": "3.1.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "5.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^4.2.2",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "file-loader": "6.1.0",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "1.7.0",
    "generator-jhipster": "^6.10.1",
    "html-loader": "0.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.14",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.7.0",
    "jasmine-reporters": "2.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.2.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-intl-shim": "1.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "karma-notify-reporter": "1.0.1",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
    "karma-sonarqube-reporter": "^1.3.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^4.0.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.11.0",
    "ngc-webpack": "3.2.2",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "0.4.0",
    "proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
    "puppeteer": "^5.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.7.1",
    "sass": "1.23.7",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.0",
    "simple-progress-webpack-plugin": "1.1.2",
    "sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
    "string-replace-webpack-plugin": "0.1.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.4",
    "typescript": "4.0.2",
    "web-app-manifest-loader": "0.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.5.0",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "4.1.0",
    "xml2js": "0.4.17"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.0"
```

Comment: Errors in the console are text. Please include text as text, not as pictures of text. Examine the whole stack to see what's calling `splitDepsDsl`, then what's calling that, etc., until you find code that you have control over. If you can't find that, start downgrading packages that you upgraded because apparently some package isn't ready for the packages you've upgraded.

Comment: Maybe you bumped npm packages that Angular version 4.3.2 does not like. For instance, I am certain `rxjs` 6.5.5 is too modern for Angular 4.3.2. The best way is to update Angular as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you changed too many packages at once. Revert your site back to when it worked, and only add one package update at a time, testing it after each update. Then you'll know what package is causing issues